# jquery subtotal amount of text fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am trying to write a jquery script to add up all textfields that have "*Amount" in the ID. I  have the following but can't figure out how to sum them all up and assign the value to a different text box.

```
<input type="text" id="1stAmount">
<input type="text" id="2ndAmount">
<input type="text" id="3rdAmount">

// to get all the values of the textboxes that have Amount in the ID
$( "input[name*='Amount']" ).value();
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all of the inputs with ids that match `Amount` by using "[id*=Amount]".   Additionally, `.val()` is the method which retrieves the value of an input.  However, this only retrieves the value of the first match:

```
$('[id*=Amount]').val();  // will be the first input's value
```

To retrieve all of the values, you have to loop through the each of the elements in the collection returned, and add up the values:

```
var total = 0;
$('[id*=Amount]').each(function(element) {
  // get the value of the current element
  var text = $(this).val();
  // add the parsed total
  total += parseFloat(text );
});

// do something with total here
alert(total)
```

Example JsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/2xpNa/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `[name*=Amount]` for getting textboxes with IDs, use `[id*=Amount]`

Use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8c7wX/)***

```
var ids = $('[id*=Amount]');
var count = 0;
$.each(ids,function(){
    count += parseFloat(this.value);
});
alert(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    var values =  $( "input[name*='Amount']" ).value();
var sum = 0;
for (int i=0;i<values.length;i++){
sum += parseInt(values[i]);
}
$("#yourTextbox").val(sum);
```